# On Irreducible Representations of $A_n$

Tags: representation-theory

I am seeking some literatures on Representation Theory of $A_n$, the alternating group of $n$ elements. Is there any article discussing the all possible Irreducible representations of $A_n$?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $A_n?$ The Weyl group of type $A_n,$ a.k.a. the symmetric group of degree $n+1?$

Comment: Or the alternating group of degree $n$...

Comment: @  jflipp, I have edited the question